# How to create a perfectly encapsulated 1-to-1 parent-child relation in EFCore 3.1?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core

Say I want to represent the following business domain:

- Every car has one odometer
- Every odometer belongs to one car
- Car knows about odometer
- Odometer does not know about car

My ideal OOP representation is something like

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public Odomoeter Odomoeter { get; }

    private Car(Guid id, Odometer odometer)
    {
         this.Id = id;
         this.Odometer = odometer;
    }

    public static Car CreateNew(Guid id) => new Car(id, Odometer.CreateNew(id));
}

public class Odometer
{
    public int Miles
    {
       get => this._miles;
       set
       {
           if (value < this._miles)
              throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot wind back odometer! ILLEGAL!");
           this._miles = value;
       }
    }

    private int _miles;

    private Odometer(Guid id, int miles)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this._miles = miles;
    }

    public static Odometer CreateNew(Guid id) => new Odometer(id, 0);
}
```

rather than aenemic like

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Odomoeter Odomoeter { get; set; }
    public Guid OdometerId { get; set; }
}

public class Odometer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Miles { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public Guid CarId { get; set; }
}
```

However, I'm not sure whether this is possible through the `HasOne...WithOne..etc.` fluent syntax. It seems you need bi-directional reference between parent and child. I know how the SQL tables should look like, quite simple:

```
       Car
=================
 Id | OdometerId

     Odometer
=================
  Id | Miles
```

However, connecting this to my encapsulated model has been a pain.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should work totally fine

```cs
public class CarConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Odometer)
                .WithOne();

        builder.HasKey(x => x.ID);
    }
}
```

Not completely sure, but you also might need one more constructor for the car without `Odometer`, otherwise EF Core most probably will throw an exception. It has a different mechanism for how it attaches the navigation properties.

```cs
private Car(Guid id)
{
    this.Id = id;
}
```